# basicHttpBinding & webHttpBinding together

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap, wcf-binding

I'm developing a WCF service with C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

I'm using `webHttpBinding` to do this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "filteredOrders/")]
OrderContract[] GetOrders(IdsMessage msg);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "completeFilteredOrders/")]
OrderContract[] LoadCompleteFilteredOrders(IdsMessage msg);
```

But now I need to send images to that Web Service using streamming and I need to add `basicHttpBinding` to do it.

**How can I do that a new `[OperationContract]` to this WCF Web Service that uses `basicHttpBinding`?**

Sorry, I'm very new on WCF development.

By the way, this is my **Web.config**:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="EReportService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="EReportService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" maxBufferSize="2097152" transferMode="Streamed"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>       
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>

  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: A possible solution: http://debugmode.net/2011/12/22/how-to-enable-rest-and-soap-both-on-the-same-wcf-service/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create another endpoint using a different address (*two endpoints cannot share the same address*) - you can modify the existing `OperationContract` to create the non-RESTful methods.

```xml
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="EReportService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="EReportService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="EReportService.IRestServiceImpl" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```